# Is it right to accept answers where some of the info is technically incorrect?

Tags: discussion

If someone answers a question in a way that includes erroneous info, but contains something else -- such as code -- which does present an answer to the question*, is it right to accept that answer (assuming there are no better ones given)?

The one I'm thinking about currently is:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36455499/5202687

Which does answer some aspects of the question, but also contains exposition which seems to be inaccurate and could be potentially misleading were it accepted.

Anyone got opinions?

*though sometimes perhaps a partial answer

Comment: Your choice really, but you might also consider creating your own correct answer when the provided answers are wrong.

Comment: Don't accept bad answers.  Deriving your own answer from an existing one is very explicitly encouraged.  Just post a link to the existing one and a link to the author.  Like "Building on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36455499/17034) posted by [@Remuse](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5779381/remuze) yadayada yadayada.

Comment: Related: [Whose choice is accepting an answer?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3914/whose-choice-is-accepting-an-answer)

Comment: Trousers sticking together?  Really?  Gromit would be appalled.

Comment: Yeah, it appears to be something to do with the way the Python I'm using functions... baffling!

Comment: I could answer that question much better.  I just wasn't here when you asked it.  Now that I *have* answered it, you won't need to accept his; just accept mine ;)

Comment: Hi @zondo , I tried your answer but the Python you provided is totally misinterpreted by the compiler, and ends up printing 'None' to the console. Or perhaps I meant to print 'None' the whole time and wasn't aware. Either way, is it right to accept?

Comment: Don't accept the answer if it's wrong.  My code doesn't print `None`, though.  If you are trying to print `philips_trousers.append(...)`, that won't work because `.append()` does the appending in-place and returns `None`.  If you have put my code in a function and tried to print the returns of the function, perhaps you forgot the `return philips_trousers` part.  I would need your code to tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: http://pythonfiddle.com/python-append outputs 'None' to the console for me...

Comment: Sorry for taking so long.  I didn't notice that you commented. (An @zondo would have helped.)  That code doesn't print anything.  Add `print philips_trousers ` to the end (no indentation) to make it print.  Oh, and if there's anything else, ask me in the comment section on my answer.  Meta doesn't seem like a good place for it.

Comment: &#42runs code&#42 oooohhhh, snazzy!

Comment: On a related note, what's the reserved character for asterisk on stack exchange???