# Which answer should the bounty be awarded to in this situation?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I've posted a bounty to one of my questions, which after the bounty was posted, gathered a fair amount of attention. Nonetheless, no answer came in which actually solved my problem, yet the discussion via comments on one of the answers, between me and the answerer, pointed me in the right direction, and I managed to solve the problem.

What is the correct procedure in this case?

- Should I award the bounty to that respective answer that pointed me in the correct direction?
- Should I let the bounty auto award itself partially to that answer?
- Should I tell the account that helped me, what was the actual problem, and ask him to formulate an answer around that problem, and then award him the bounty?
- Should I write my own answer to the question, and let the bounty auto-award itself between the other answers?

Comment: You should post your own answer, using what you learned from the comments.  Awarding the bounty is neither necessary nor possible if there are no answers, you got its intended effect.  Looks like you have 3 more days on the bounty, a better answer might still show up.

Comment: This indeed seems like the correct way to go, based on the rules of the bounties, yet it still seems a bit harsh to me, as I wasn't able to solve my problem, without the help of that specific account.

Comment: Ping the comment author and ask if they are willing to expand the comment into an answer. Even a partial answer is sometimes helpful. You can always add your own more complete answer separately.

Comment: @usr2564301 You should make that answer. I think that is the respectable thing to do. If the author declines, then do as Hans mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partial answer to a similar question (sans the bounty) is in the comments in [Partial answer in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292140/2564301).

Ping the comment author and ask if they are willing to expand the comment into an answer. Even a partial answer is sometimes helpful.

You can always add your own more complete answer separately.

You don't have to *accept* the partial answer ([Is it right to accept answers where some of the info is technically incorrect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320568/2564301) (unanswered but see the comments)), but you are free to assign the bonus to any answer you felt was most helpul.